# Simon's algorithm in quantum computing

Tags: algorithms, quantum-computing

I am curios how simon's algorithm works and I have read this post
[Simple explanation of Simon's Problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19519/simple-explanation-of-simons-problem) but still is not clear for me.

I have found on th internet this example https://www.cs.vu.nl/~tcs/ac/ac-11_simon_algorithm.pdf. Can somebody explain how are calculated the value of Simon's algorithm?

If we take the above example:

f(000) = f(011) = 010.

**How are the values obtained?**

**Can somebody explain the algorithm or knows a good source where this is explained well?**

Thank you

Comment: Would the close-voter who claims that this isn't computer science explain their reasoning? It looks like a CS question to me. Quantum computation seems to be obviously CS, to me. Further, the question clearly shows the research that the asker has done and indicates a specific part of the material that they don't understand.

Comment: "How are the values obtained?" The function f is part of the input for the problem, so the values are somewhat arbitrary. Related: [how exactly does Simons algorithm solve the Simons problem](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1710/)